# SQL Server BDC Pools and Performance

Tags: t-sql, hdfs, query-performance, webhdfs, sql-server-2019

Against an AKS based SQL Server 2019 BDC, I loaded the [Flight_delay](https://www.kaggle.com/usdot/flight-delays) dataset that is available at `www.kaggle.com`. I wanted to test the performance of the various data stores, ie, master instance, data pool, HDFS-storage pool and ADLS-storage pool (via HDFS Tiering).

Against the pools - data pool, HDFS-storage pool and ADLS-storage pool - I created External tables to access as shown in the script below.

```
Select Count(*)
From [dbo].[Master_Flights]  F
Inner join [dbo].[Master_Airports] A on F.ORIGIN_AIRPORT = A.IATA_CODE
Inner join [dbo].[Master_Airlines] L on F.AIRLINE = L.IATA_CODE
GO

Select Count(*)
From [dbo].[DataPool_Flights]  F
Inner join [dbo].[DataPool_Airports] A on F.ORIGIN_AIRPORT = A.IATA_CODE
Inner join [dbo].[DataPool_Airlines] L on F.AIRLINE = L.IATA_CODE
GO

Select Count(*)
From [dbo].[HDFS_StoragePool_Flights]  F
Inner join [dbo].[HDFS_StoragePool_Airports] A on F.ORIGIN_AIRPORT = A.IATA_CODE
Inner join [dbo].[HDFS_StoragePool_Airlines] L on F.AIRLINE = L.IATA_CODE
GO

Select Count(*)
From [dbo].[adls_StoragePool_Flights]  F
Inner join [dbo].[adls_StoragePool_Airports] A on F.ORIGIN_AIRPORT = A.IATA_CODE
Inner join [dbo].[adls_StoragePool_Airlines] L on F.AIRLINE = L.IATA_CODE
GO
```

The performance from "best to worst":

1. Master Instance - 2 seconds
2. Data Pool   - 16 seconds
3. HDFS-Storage Pool - 90 seconds
4. ADLS-Storage Pool - 220 seconds

Are my test results on expected lines? I was hoping to get pretty good performance results for the data pool option at least.

If the performance is this bad for the tables in the pools why would anyone want to use them?

Thanks,
grajee

Answer (score 1):

let's ignore the ADLS for now - there is too much other stuff (network latency between regions etc.) involved.

This might be an indexing or IO issue.

How big is you AKS cluster (machine family and node count)?
How do the numbers compare when running the count JUST against the fact table (flights) without joining?
How does the HDFS perform when you convert the CSV to parquet?

Ben

Comment: The machine family for AKS cluster is Standard_E8_v3 with 3 nodes and I selected Premium Disks.  
I did not create any index as I was hoping that the Columnstore index would suffice. 

I ran a count(*) from [Master_Flights], [DataPool_Flights] and [HDFS_StoragePool_Flights] and out of 20 secs 
that the three queries took, [HDFS_StoragePool_Flights] took 18 secs.
Is there any other that you want me to test?

I will try with Parquet file later today.

Comment: I tried the below with Flights data being in the data pool and it took 16 secs just the way it ran when all the tables are in the data pool. This is lot more compared to the time taken for queries with all the tables in the Master instance

Select Count(*)
From [dbo].[Master_Flights]  F
Inner join [dbo].[Master_Airports] A on F.ORIGIN_AIRPORT = A.IATA_CODE
Inner join [dbo].[Master_Airlines] L on F.AIRLINE = L.IATA_CODE

Comment: So Master Instance and Data Pool are both below 1 Second for the COUNT(*)?

Comment: For the storage pool, its pods will grab everything they can on whatever worker nodes they land on, therefore you are best to use node labels to dedicate specific workers to the storage pool pods.